# Использование переменной в where в oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Как использовать переменные в where? Конструкция вида:

Первый select возвращает единственное значение (отрабатывает корректно). Проблема при вызове переменной во втором select.

```
declare 
  myVar date;
begin
  select myField
  into   :myVar
  from   myTable; 

  select *
  into   col
  from   secondTable
  where  secField > &myVar
  and    rownum < 2;
end;
```

Данная конструкция не отрабатывает.
Интересует именно такая конструкция - обходные решения знаю.

Comment: А вопрос то в чем?

Comment: Удалил ответ, судя по всему не отвечающий на ваш вопрос. Сформлируйте вопрос более точно. Не понятно, что вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Задача: необходимо в oracle-переменную занести результат запроса(select). После этого, эту переменная используется в where clause следующего запроса. Я привел пример, как это делал я. Меня устроят любые альтернативные варианты. Извините за некорректность, но не знаю как его правильней задать.

Comment: И все таки, чем вас не устроил ответ, который дали и потом удалили ? Переменные в Oracle в запросах участвуют без каких либо двоеточий или амперсандов перед ними. просто "как есть". Разумеется ни одна переменная не должна называться так же как какая нибудь колонка в таблице с которой вы работаете, что бы интерпретатор не перепутал их

Comment: Не устроил. Я его протестировал - он не работает, если не доверяете можете проверить самостоятельно.

Comment: Я проверил аналогичный на своих таблицах - все отлично работает. Что вы ожидаете получить в результате выполнения этого блока ? Как вы понимаете работает он или нет, если получаемое вторым запросом значение никуда не пишите ?

Comment: @Mike, скинь плз свой рабочий вариант. Переменная используется след. образом во втором запросе: insert into ... (select ... from ...  where <condition on myVar>). В общем, необходимо занести данные в таблицу в зависимости от того, как myVar зарезолвилась

Comment: `declare myVar date;
col date;
begin
select dt
into myVar
from v1users where usid=27; 

select dt
into col
from v1users
where dt > myVar
and rownum < 2;
end;
`

Comment: Если запрос не выдает ошибок компиляции - значит он должен быть рабочим. если при этом он не выдает ожидаемых данных то проблемы не в конструкции запроса и того как написаны переменные, а в чем то другом. Например нет подходящих данных или вы забываете дать commit _после_ выполнения блока и пытаетесь найти данные из другой сессии

Comment: И кстати, я думал это некий общий вопрос про блоки pl/sql и переменные. Потому как все, что написано у вас в блоке легко делается одним запросом без всяких переменных и собственно блоков pl/sql

Comment: @Mike, твое решение работает. Спасибо за помощь! да я знаю, что можно через подзапрос, но по некоторым причинам, нужно сделать через переменную.

Comment: Хм. но приведенный и удаленный ответ абсолютно такой же, только описка при объявлении переменной. написано `col varcahr2(100);` вместо `col varchar2(100);`

Comment: @lDrakonl Предлагаю восстановить ваш ответ и исправить там описку (varchar2(100)). Потому как точно такой же протестированный мной блок заработал у ТС :)

Comment: @Mike спасибо. Восстановил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас блок PL\SQL кода. Вот рабочий вариант того, что у вас написано. Без уточнения задачи тяжело понять, что Вы спрашиваете. Предполагается, что в таблице `secondTable` есть колонка с названием `col1`.
В блоке результат запроса должен быть куда то сохранен, нельзя написать селект не сказав, куда поместить его результат.
Так же я дописал условие `rownum < 2`, так как в переменную нельзя вернуть более 1го значения(это приведет к ошибке)

```
declare 
  myVar date;
  col   varchar2(100);
begin
  select myField
  into   myVar
  from   myTable; 

  select t.col1 
  into   col
  from   secondTable t
  where  secField > myVar
  and    rownum < 2;
end;
```

Comment: Конструкция не работает

Comment: Поясните, что значит "не работает" ? Не выполняет поставленную задачу(если да, то что она должна сделать)? Возвращает ошибку?

Comment: спасибо! после правок работает)

Comment: @meowmeow тогда нажмите галочку, принять ответ как верный.